# Где взять справочник с кодами подразделений, выдающих паспорта?

Tags: поиск-данных

Для автозаполнения полей в CRM не хватает справочника подразделений, которые выдают паспорта. Чтобы при вводе кода подразделения подтягивалось значение в поле "Кем выдан" паспорт.

Поделитесь, где найти такую базу?

Comment: Связанный вопрос на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9804/213987

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/hflabs/fms-unit
Поковыряйте тут, описание есть

Comment: Кстати, да, помню как её составляли: https://habr.com/en/company/hflabs/blog/442012/